# How to fetch links from search results using fileoutputstream in jmeter (url:www.ask.com, search result:Buddha quotes)

Tags: jmeter

[image]How to fetch Buddha quotes links from above provided url using file output stream in jmeter and what would be exact regular expression?

Answer (score 1):

1. It's better to use [CSS Selector Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS_Selector_Extractor), it is [not recommended to use regular expressions in order to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), the relevant configuration would be something like:

   - Name of created variable: `link`
   - CSS Selector Expression: `a[class=PartialSearchResults-item-title-link result-link]`
   - Attribute: `href`

     It will produce the following [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) like:

     ```
     link_1=http://wisdomquotes.com/buddha-quotes/
     link_2=https://ideapod.com/100-quotes-buddha-will-change-spend-life/
     link_3=https://www.brainyquote.com/authors/buddha
     link_4=https://lifehacks.io/inspirational-famous-buddha-quotes/
     link_5=https://www.keepinspiring.me/buddha-quotes/
     link_6=http://www.planetofsuccess.com/blog/2017/enlightening-buddha-quotes/
     link_7=http://www.quoteambition.com/inspirational-buddha-quotes-sayings/
     link_8=https://www.realbuddhaquotes.com/
     link_9=https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/tag/buddhism
     link_matchNr=9
     ```
2. It's better to use [JSR223 Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Listener), since JMeter 3.1 [it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for any form of scripting as in the majority of cases [Groovy acts faster than Beanshell](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black). The code would be something like:

   ```
   keyword = 'buddha quotes'
   file = new File('result00.csv')

   file << keyword << ','

   1.upto(vars.get('link_matchNr') as int, {
       file << vars.get("link_$it") << ' '
   })
   ```
3. As the result you will have the file looking like:

   ```
   buddha quotes,http://wisdomquotes.com/buddha-quotes/ https://ideapod.com/100-quotes-buddha-will-change-spend-life/ https://www.brainyquote.com/authors/buddha https://lifehacks.io/inspirational-famous-buddha-quotes/ https://www.keepinspiring.me/buddha-quotes/ http://www.planetofsuccess.com/blog/2017/enlightening-buddha-quotes/ http://www.quoteambition.com/inspirational-buddha-quotes-sayings/ https://www.realbuddhaquotes.com/ https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/tag/buddhism buddha quotes,http://wisdomquotes.com/buddha-quotes/ https://ideapod.com/100-quotes-buddha-will-change-spend-life/ https://www.brainyquote.com/authors/buddha https://lifehacks.io/inspirational-famous-buddha-quotes/ https://www.keepinspiring.me/buddha-quotes/ http://www.planetofsuccess.com/blog/2017/enlightening-buddha-quotes/ http://www.quoteambition.com/inspirational-buddha-quotes-sayings/ https://www.realbuddhaquotes.com/ https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/tag/buddhism
   ```

Comment: Thank u so much for ur clear explanation it useful to me alot@Dmitri